# how to join some text before user input text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey How Can I Add Lines In User Input Texts Like

Name: User Input Value

Ex :- Name: John Doe

This Code Worked But Not That I Want

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#confirm-btn').on('click', function () {
        var form = $('.shamweel-custom-form').not('#ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message');
        var vals = form.map(function () {
            var value = $.trim(this.value)
            return value ? value : undefined;
        }).get();
        var billingInputData = vals.join(',' + '\n');
        $('#ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message').val(billingInputData);   
    });
});
```

It Gives

John Doe,

Johndoe@gmail.com,

Etc

But I Want It to Work Like

Name: John Doe,

Email: johndoe@gmail.com,
Etc.